# Is accessing a read-only static variable better or worse than repeatedly retrieving data from an Azure blob?

Tags: c#, azure, performance, static, blob

I have about 5,000 read-only records.

Typically I store records in an Azure blob, and a function will retrieve the data, search through them, and then return matching records to the end-user.

Is it efficient and safe to, instead, retrieve the data from the Azure blob *once*, store it in a static variable, and then search through that?

I've looked and looked, but I can't find a comparison or discussion between (a) repeatedly retrieving data from an Azure blob vs. (b) just maintaining it in a static variable, and why that might be undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues with repeatedly retrieving data from an Azure blob:

- Every retrieve (read) operation is a chargeable transaction so your Azure bill will go up.
- Every retrieve (read) operation is a network call which might fail so you have to take that into consideration. Furthermore, it will add time to your overall request process.

Issues with maintaining it in a static variable:

- Static variables will consume server memory.

Not sure how big these files are but if they are not big, then I would recommend storing them in static variables if your blobs are truly read-only (i.e. will not change).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a Cache-Aside pattern use-case. Load data on demand into a cache from a data store. This can improve performance and also helps to maintain consistency between data held in the cache and data in the underlying data store.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside

Comment: Thank you - that does sound like an applicable pattern I hadn't quite identified.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with what Gaurav suggested. I have used similar pattern with my azure functions. I generally load the variables in static variables and keep using it. you should keep in mind that your azure function would run from a container and the azure function runtime can load multiple containers on demand. So please remember to do a null check on your static variable. considering that your 5000 records are not very big (few Kb each), you will not incur a lot of bill. Also the performance would be much better.

Comment: I do - they're initialized with a static function call which pulls the data from its Azure blob. Whenever it's spun up the first thing it does is call that function and populates the static variable with data.

If the blob happens to be empty it instantiates and returns an empty set of objects rather than null, too.

Do you know if there's any specific reading / MSDN that addresses this? Or is this just knowledge people have acquired? I couldn't find anything on the subject.

Comment: For me this is more of a knowledge that I have acquired doing trial and error. And I can guarantee you this works as we have implemented this in some business critical large scale apps. You can learn more about the function runtime from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#parallel-execution .